# Ability to send Reports via email to a group of users on an hourly basis

Tags: apex, email, reporting, scheduled-apex, custom-reports

I want to know that whether it is possible to send reports data as a content via email to a group of users, on an hourly basis and during the business hours only.

I am aware of the standard Salesforce functionality that sends the link to the report, but it does only for once in a day. But my need is to rather send the data returned by the report as an email on an hourly basis.

Can anyone please suggest?

Comment: Check out document generation apps like Conga Composer or Drawloop.  If they don't fit the bill, then you could try using the [Reports and Dashboards API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_analytics_intro.htm) to retrieve the report data and send it out via scheduled Apex.

Answer (score 1):

You can use that particular report in an automation and run it on hourly basis. This would be the only option available, I guess, to meet your requirement for now :)